# vertex and fragment shader values in webgl

Tags: webgl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm new to webgl.I was wondering how the vertex and fragment shader values are generated.
 I was seeing some samples and could see a huge array of these values.Couldnt figure out how these values are getting generated.Are there any tools to generate these values.
Am I missing something? No tutorial was explaining on how to create these shader values.
Any help in this is appreciated.

Comment: If you tell us what sort of samples you were looking at, maybe we can tell you how the values are generated. Are you talking about vertex coordinate values?

Comment: http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/aquarium/aquarium.html.They have huge values defined in their js files.Didnt understand how they were able to generate so big values.

Answer (score 3):

What you are most likely seeing is their vertex or index buffer information. These are typically stored as large arrays of floats or ints like so:

[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]

This could, depending on the vertex layout represent, a position, texture coordinate, and normal for a single vertex, like so:

Position: (x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0)
Texcoord: (u: 0.5, v: 0.5)
Normal: (x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)

And you'll usually get a whole bunch of them smashed together into one big long array. These are terribly difficult to read, but are usually generated by a modeling tool exporter and sent straight to the GPU so there's typically not much human interaction.

I did a little [write up](http://blog.tojicode.com/2011/05/interleaved-array-basics.html) a while back about how you tell WebGL to interpret those values, but I'm not sure exactly how much you know about 3D Geometry so that might be a bit too high level. Some of the early Learning WebGL lessons cover it in a bit more detail:

[Lesson 1](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=28), [Lesson 2](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=134)

Answer (score 0):

Just use some 3D modeling tool, you kno, like Blender, Maya, 3D Studio Max, Google Sketch up, doesn't matter really.

These values you talk about are generated by these programs when you create a model in it, like, you want to create a fish, then you open up your 3D modeling tool, do your work there and then export this into one of the many file formats for 3D models, there is .x, .fbx, collada etc. The resulting file will contain all the information you need to render this 3D fish anywhere you want, it will contain the vertices positions, texture coordinates, normals (used for lighting mostly), maybe colors and a bunch of other things.

So you just have to chose one of these file formats, learn how to get the data you need out of it, put it in a way that could be evaluated by javascript (those arrays you said) and pass the information to the vertex/fragment shaders.